# Why do I get ColdFusion errors that my components are undefined?

Tags: coldfusion, components

Several times a day, I get error for my application that different components are undefined. I'm baffled by this, because the components ARE defined, and generally make up the core of the application, so they are accessed correctly most of the time. Here is an example:

```
coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedElementException: 
  Element CFC.CHAPTER is undefined in a Java object of 
  type class [Ljava.lang.String; referenced as ''
```

I have these components defined in my Application.cfc file like so:

```
<cfset application.cfc = structNew()>

<cfset local.cfcList = "Chapter,Chat,Collection,Comments,Contribution">

<cfloop list="#local.cfcList#" index="local.thisCfcName">
  <cfset application.cfc[local.thisCfcName] = createObject(
    "component",
    "#application.cfcPath##local.thisCfcName#"
  )>
</cfloop>
```

I assume somehow the component doesn't get created, but I don't know why that would be happening. Is there a better way to do this that is more reliable?

Thank you.
John

Comment: This may see like a strange question, but here goes. Are you trying to load a bunch of cfc's that may or may not even exist? Maybe you need to test for the cfc's existence before trying  create one.

Comment: I am loading a lot of cfc's (maybe 25), but they do all exist. I double-checked that they were all there and spelled correctly.

Comment: What line of code is that actual error coming from.  Note that it's saying the key doesn't exist in a STRING.  Somewhere in your code is a variable that you think is going to be a struct, but it's a string instead.  You need to track where the error is, wrap it in a try/catch and dump out the related variables to visualize them.  That might give you a hint as to what's going on.  I would check for race conditions in your init code you posted. Is your site reinitting while other pages are trying to access the cfc struct? Also, use WireBox :)

Comment: Looking at how you are initializing these cfcs, you should subsequently be referencing them like so: `application.cfc.Chapter`. However, the error indicates that you are not... it thinks that `application` is a string and not a struct, and therefore cannot contain `cfc.Chapter`. Do you have a line number where the exception is being generated? Can you post an example of how you are accessing these? @BradWood has a point... if your initialization code is being executed at the same time that these components are being initialized, then you could get that error. Check applicationTimeout.

Comment: Here is an example of one that throws an error frequently:   <cfset group_permission = application.cfc.groups.get_member(
    group_id = #book.groups_id#,
    person_id = #client.pid#
   )>

Comment: I don't know if this sheds any light, but the error occurs in a cfinclude, which uses a variable defined in application (application.includeHref). cfc.groups gets called in both the include file and the main file. Maybe there is a conflict? I am trying to use cflock around both references, in case.

Comment: As Brad and @Redtopia asked, do you have a line number or   better yet the complete error message? More context would help... Also, where in the Application.cfc are the components initialized - OnApplicationStart?